# How to remove a character from a string and convert the rest into integer or decimal, for all values in a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

example : 
I want to convert all values under the column item price at once so that they do not have the '$' sign.

```
order_id        item_price
0                $2.39
1                $3.39
2                $3.39
3                $2.39
4               $16.98
```

Comment: Please consider adding the sample data in code. Also, please share what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can see the pandas documentation.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric

https://datatofish.com/string-to-integer-dataframe/

I did this example in my head without test: `pd.to_numeric(your_df.price.str.replace("$", ""))`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    df['columnname'][i] = df['columnname'][i].replace('$',' ')
df
```

or faster way maybe

```py
df.columnname = [x.replace('$',' ') for x in df.columnname]
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps... but is there a more general way of doing it using a pandas method or function..??

Comment: there is something new, hope it helps